# invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘std::string& from an rvalue of type ‘std::basic_string<char>

Tags: c++, string, c++11

```
bool hasWord(int y, int x, string &word) {
    if(!inRange(y, x)) return false; 
    if(board[y][x] != word[0])  return false; 
    if(word.size() == 1) return true; 
    for(int direction = 0; direction < 8; direction++) {
        int nextX = x + dx[direction];
        int nextY = y + dy[direction];
        if(hasWord(nextY, nextX, word.substr(1)))  // <--- This
            return true;
    }
return false; }
```

error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘std::string& {aka std::basic_string&}’ from an rvalue of type ‘std::basic_string’
   if(hasWord(nextY, nextX, word.substr(1)))

why the reason I was wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The error message says it all: *invalid initialization of non-const reference of type `std::string` {aka `std::basic_string`} from an rvalue of type `std::basic_string`*.

I.e. a reference to non-const cannot be bound to a temporary object (aka r-value). That temporary object is created by `word.substr(1)` expression.

In declaration:

```
bool hasWord(int y, int x, string &word)
```

Make it `string const& word`, since you do not need a modifiable `word`.

Answer (score 3):

The reason of the error is that in this call

```
if(hasWord(nextY, nextX, word.substr(1))) 
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

there is created a temporary object of the type std::string and you are trying to bind a non-constant reference with the temporary object.

If the string is not changed in the function then just declare the function  like

```
bool hasWord(int y, int x, const string &word) {
                           ^^^^^
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you wish to convert to non const reference of type std::string& from rvalue std::string, you could do something like:

```
auto stringRef = std::string(<string_value>);
```

and pass on the value.